# agree on that clause?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, clauses

I wrote this sentence one day.

"I agree with the author on that the structure of the poem is unusual."

I read it again and found it a little strange.

I knew that that-clauses cannot be used after a preposition directly except in special cases (like this one! except!).

So I did a quick check with one of my friends and had him read it, and he said it sounds fine. But I had doubts.

Is it grammatical to put that-clause after "agree on"? Or for that matter, with any other prepositions except "in" and "except"?

Thank you!

Comment: You might agree with the author on one point, and that point might be that the structure of the poem is unusual, but the above sentence is more than simply unusual -- it's wrong.  Did you perhaps mean to say "I agree with the author **in that** the structure of the poem is unusual"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *that* as a conjunction to link the two clauses, you cannot end the first clause with the preposition *on*. Read it by itself:

> I agree with the author on

It is ungrammatical. You can either remove *on* or *that*, though you might have to do a little restructuring:

1. I agree with the author that the structure of the poem is unusual.
2. I agree with the author's comments on the poem's unusual structure.

I prefer the latter.